# Click/select selectize field with selenium/webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, meteor, webdriver, selectize.js

I am running a [cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) test with [chimp.js](https://chimp.readme.io/docs/getting-started) under [meteor.js](https://www.meteor.com/).

I would like to click and select an item from a [selectized](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/)  field with selenium/webdriver.io. Moreover, but probably irrelevant, I use the [reactive-selectize](https://github.com/mologie/meteor-reactive-selectize) package under meteor.

While my testing environment under chrome is processing, I defined to run the following action with [selenium/webdriver.io](https://chimp.readme.io/docs/key-concepts); in my step I tried the following alternatives:

```
browser.click('#select'); // Alternative A
browser.click('div.selectize-control'); // Alternative B
browser.click('div.selectize-input'); // Alternative C
```

None of these actions triggered the opening of the selectize dropdown list.

However, if I try

```
browser.execute(function(bookshop_id) {
  var $sel = $('#new-order-bookshop').selectize()[0];
  $sel.selectize.setValue('bpS3E8t3PLRnd8YWZ'); // select value via selectize
}, bookshop_id);
```

It re-runs selectize on the select field, so all my s are gone. I guess, I am overwriting the options that my meteor app originally generated. I could manually add options/items, but this is rather an awkward solution.

How can I select items of a selectize field with selenium/webdriver.io?

Comment: Strange enough, if I run
`browser.click('div.selectize-input');
browser.click('div.selectize-dropdown-content > div');`
on a selectized <input> field (and not <select> as in the example), everything works!